# Update query array with addition or deletion of sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm new to coding and have been trying to find some help but may not have been searching the correct terms so I would appreciate any direction I can get!

I am using a query in multiple locations with different criteria but the same array for all. I am looking for a way for the query array to be updated as sheets are added or removed from the spreadsheet without having to do it manually each time. I would need to leave out certain sheets. This is an example of the query I am using below.

```
=IFERROR(QUERY({'Test Location 1'!C6:P;'Test Location 2'!C6:P;'Test Location 3'!C6:P},"SELECT Col11,Col14 WHERE Col4='Working On It' and Col5='Yellow Station'",1),"")
```

[Test Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lA7HbO8ubKf8i7Hj6-gi5MZACiviTZpyynyh1pnTnQE/edit#gid=1214320161)

[image]

Comment: so you have now the sheet names and gids and you want some universal formula which will work regardless if you delete the whole sheet?

Comment: Pretty much. The only thing that is common with all the formulas is the array: {'Test Location 1'!C6:P;'Test Location 2'!C6:P;'Test Location 3'!C6:P}. Looking for that array to update automatically if I were to delete Test Location 1 or add a Test Location 4 but not include certain sheets. If you open the sample, I would want to exclude the Overview, Working On It, and Lists.

Comment: @player0 Just brainstorming here but is there a way to take the list with the active sheets and GIDs we created and filter it to only the sheets I want to build the array? Included a picture in the post.

Comment: well it can be easily QUERY-ed out `"where Col1 contains 'Test'"`

Comment: @player0 Thank you! I have it pulling the correct list of sheets I would like but I'm wondering if there is a way to combine them into a usable array to use in my query. I have the range from each sheet on the right all joined together to form the array I would like in the top cell. Unfortunately, it does not let me use that as my array.